# How to make an queue array that can hold both strings and integers?

Tags: java, arrays, queue, user-input

I have to create an array that will hold a user input that is 3 letter code followed by a ticket number. ex) Ama-34. How do I do this?
I know long is not correct, I just am modeling it off of another project.
I also have to allow for user input and manipulation which I am having a hard time.
This is what I have so far...

```
class QueueOrder{
    
    //Global Variables
    static Scanner orderScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Variables
    public int MaxSize;
    //How to make an array hold both names and numbers??
    public long[] BodaciousArray; 
    public int Front;  //Track the front pointer
    public int Rear;   //track the last pointer 
    public int NumberOfOrders; //track the number of orders in the system
    
    //Constructor
    public QueueOrder(int size){
        
        MaxSize = size;
        BodaciousArray = new long[MaxSize];
        Front = 0;
        Rear = -1;
        NumberOfOrders = 0;
    }
    
    //Enqueue - add to the rear of the queue
    //Allow the server to add one to the array
    public void Enqueue(){
        long j = 0;
        //Add a wrap around
        if(Rear == MaxSize - 1){           
            Rear = -1;
        }
        //Increment the rear and insert a new item
        BodaciousArray[++Rear] = j;
        NumberOfOrders++;
    }
   
    //Dequeue - remove one from the array
    //Allow the server to remove what is next in line
    public long Dequeue(){
        //Get the first value and incrament the front
        long temp = BodaciousArray[Front++];
        //Add a wrap around
        if(Front == MaxSize){
            Front = 0;
        }
        //Remove one item
        NumberOfOrders--;
        return temp;                
    }
    
    //Peek at the front of the queue
    //Allow the server to see what order is next
    public long peekFront(){
        return BodaciousArray[Front];
    }
    
    //Check to is the queue is empty
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return(NumberOfOrders == 0);
    }
    
    //Check to see if the queue is full
    public boolean isFull(){
        return(NumberOfOrders == MaxSize);
    }
    
    //Check how many items are in the queue
    public int size(){
        return NumberOfOrders;
    }
    
    public void DisplayQueueOrder(){
        int i;
        if(Front == Rear){
            System.out.println("There are no orders to fill");
        }else{
            for(i = Front; i < Rear; i++){
                System.out.print("The current orders are: " 
                        + BodaciousArray[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the two seperate, and the 3 letter code is unique [HashMap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) is the way to go:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> queueArray = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
queueArray.put("Ama", 34);
System.out.println(arr.get("Ama"));
```

outputs:

```
34
```

Otherwise, why not just do something like this:

```
String[] tickets = {"Ama-34", "Abc-60", "Xyz-76"};

public String getTicketCode(int index) {
    return tickets[index].split("-")[0];
}

public int getTicketNumber(int index) {
    return Integer.parseInt(tickets[index].split("-")[1]);
}
```

used like:

```
System.out.println(getTicketCode(0));
System.out.println(getTicketNumber(0));
```

prints:

```
Ama
76
```

Comment: Okay, awesome. Thank you! I set it to a string instead of a long. I do need them to print together like (Ama - 42).